# How do I use a font not installed in my computer in Visual Basic?

Tags: vb.net, text, visual-studio-2012, fonts

How do I use a font not installed in my computer in Visual Basic and the font file is in my resources?

I tried this but I guess it only works when the file is not on the resources.

```
    Imports System.Drawing.Text

    Public Class frmTitle
        Private Sub frmTitle_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
            Dim myFont As New PrivateFontCollection()
            myFont.AddFontFile(My.Resources.font_space_invaders)
            lblPressStart.Font = New Font(myFont.Families(0), 20, FontStyle.Bold)
        End Sub
    End Class
```

Comment: If you don't want to use a file then use [AddMemoryFont() instead](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16374632/embedded-font-causes-a-crash).

Comment: Well, don't repeat the same mistake of course.  Remove the Marshal.FreeCoTaskMem() call.

Comment: @HansPassant The error at the label happened again but this time, it only happens when the form where the label is closed and showed again.

Comment: @HansPassant To be more specific, the error occurs when a moving picturebox intersects to the boundary of that label.

Answer (score 0):

How about trying like [this](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/107377/Load-And-Use-Custom-Font-Without-Installing-It):-

```
PrivateFontCollection pfc = new PrivateFontCollection();
pfc.AddFontFile("C:\\Path To\\PALETX3.ttf");
label1.Font = new Font(pfc.Families[0], 16, FontStyle.Regular);
```

Comment: Tried it but it doesn't work when the file is on the resources.